# Added AFNetworking via cocoapods - AFHTTPClient.h/m are not included

Tags: ios7, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

When I use cocoapods to add AFNetworking to my workspace, everything appears to be in place but I am unable to instantiate any AFHTTPClient instances in my code.  The files: AFHTTPClient.h and .m are not present anywhere within the AFNetworking hierarchy.

Currently, my Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Parse',        '1.2.17'
```

And my CLI pod update command runs fine from the terminal as shown below:

```
nmaster >> pod update
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (2.0.3)
Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.11.0)
Using Parse (1.2.17)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

The error I am seeing in my code is shown below:

[image: code snippet]

I've seen a number of posts referring to the HEADER SEARCH PATH being insufficient but I've already confirmed that the files themselves do not exist.  Has AFHTTPClient been deprecated?  I did find a copy in one of Ray W.'s tutorials of both the AFHTTPClient.h and .m files and tried to drag/drop those into my project but that led to duplicate references and other problemos.

Anyone have any ideas of where I should attack this problem?

Thanks, Phil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AFHTTPClient` has been replaced by other classes in AFNetworking version 2.0. See also here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide.  If you specify version 1.6.x (from memory) and iOS 6.1 in your podfile, you can still use the old version and keep your code.